# Constructing a cumulative distribution function from a histogram

Tags: object-oriented, statistics, constructor, kotlin

During some running process, a histogram of values shall be build up. When done, the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) shall be derived from it and used to get the quantiles for some values.

My current implementation looks as follows:

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.math.max
import kotlin.math.min
import kotlin.math.roundToInt
import kotlin.random.Random


// 10 buckets for interval [0, 1000], outliers will be clamped
class Histogram(
    private val data: MutableMap<Int, Int> = mutableMapOf()
) {
    fun add(value: Int) {
        val bucket = max(0, min(1000, value)) / 100
        data[bucket] = data.getOrDefault(bucket, 0) + 1
    }

    fun deriveCDF(): CDF {
        val sum = data.values.sum()
        val pdfData = data.toSortedMap().mapValues { it.value.toDouble() / sum }
        val cdfData: MutableMap<Int, Double> = mutableMapOf()
        var acc = 0.0
        pdfData.forEach {
            acc += pdfData.getOrDefault(it.key, 0.0)
            cdfData[it.key] = acc
        }
        return CDF(cdfData.toSortedMap())
    }
}


// cumulative distribution function
class CDF(
    private val data: SortedMap<Int, Double>
) {
    fun getQuantile(value: Double): Double? {
        val bucket = (10 * value).roundToInt()
        return data[bucket]
    }
}


fun main() {
    val hist = Histogram()
    List(10000) {
        Random.nextInt(0, 1000)
    }.forEach {
        hist.add(it)
    }
    val cdf = hist.deriveCDF()
    println(cdf.getQuantile(0.3))
}
```

My problem with this is, that is it possible to construct instances of `CDF` with `SortedMap`s as `data` that don't make sense. I would like to prevent this, already at compile time.

The obvious alternative approach is to not have the construction logic (`Histogram` to `CDF`) in a `Histogram::deriveCDF`, but instead have a constructor of `CDF` take a `Histogram` instance and do the math there. This however forces `Histogram` to expose its internals `data: MutableMap<Int, Int>`, i.e., make them `public`, for the constructor of `CDF` to access them. But I would like to keep this implementation detail of `Histogram` hidden.

How can I escape this dilemma?

Comment: *it possible to construct instances of CDF with SortedMaps as data that don't make sense. I would like to not allow this.* - Have you considered doing validation in the constructor and throwing an exception?

Comment: @SimonForsberg Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, this would be possible, but I'd prefer the type system already preventing me from doing so, instead of detecting such a mistake only at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem starts here:

```
val cdfData: MutableMap<Int, Double> = mutableMapOf()
```

This is the data that you want to your CDF class, but anyone can make a mutable map anywhere and use it for tons of things. So this is what you want to hide. So put this inside a `CDFBuilder`

```
class CDFBuilder {
     private val cdfData: MutableMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Double>()

     fun withData(a: Int, b: Double): CDFBuilder {
          // verification and stuff
          cdfData[a] = b
          return this
     }
}
```

Now, the problem is to build the `CDF` class without letting anyone else do it, right? There are a few options here:

1. Make a copy of the `cdfData` public from the `CDFBuilder` and read it in the CDF constructor, passing a `CDFBuilder` to the constructor.

Or 2, make a private constructor on the CDF-class, allowing it to only be constructed from the builder:

```
class CDF private constructor(val map: SortedMap<Int, Double>) {

    class CDFBuilder {
        private val cdfData: MutableMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Double>()

        fun withData(a: Int, b: Double): CDFBuilder {
            // verification and stuff
            cdfData[a] = b
            return this
        }

        fun build(): CDF {
            return CDF(map.toSortedMap())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea. It looked good at the beginning, but if I understand correctly, it does not solve the actual problem.

Now still anybody can just build invalid `CDF`s from somewhere without providing a `Histogram`, because one can just instantiate a `CDF.CDFBuilder()` and put some values in it, as shown in this snippet: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/6cc56e940f3b135dd9f6f04cb53c4ce2

Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TobiasHermann Well, I was thinking that you would have validation in your `build()` method, or in the `addData`. But if you have the requirement to have a *Histogram* and not just *data that also makes a valid Histogram* then you could use the same trick by having your `Histogram` have access to the `CDL`'s private constructor. Or have `Histogram` and `CDL` be in the same package and not have anything else in the same package, and have the `CDL` have a package-scoped constructor.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I understand the package-scoped constructor, and I like the idea. But you also wrote "having your `Histogram` have access to the `CDL`'s private constructor", which spikes my interest. But I don't yet understand how to implement this. Could you show me?

Comment: @TobiasHermann Make `Histogram` the inner class and `CDF` the outer class, similar to CDF and CDFBuilder in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. A solution using nested/inner classes seems best to me. For completeness, it's also possible to make `Histogram` the outer class and `CDF` the nested class, like [this](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/1eb0a903c61d7dd489283d118b102ea8).

Comment: @TobiasHermann Ah yes, there you don't depend on the private constructor so that works. However, you are not guaranteed that the data in the `Histogram` is valid, as you could do `Histogram(mutableMapOf(10000000 to -2147483648))` to create a histogram with invalid data. Putting the `private val data: MutableMap<Int, Int> = mutableMapOf()` right above the `add` method would however solve that problem.

Comment: You are totally right. Thanks again. I'll post this solution as an answer too here, for possible future readers.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (thanks a lot again to [Simon Forsberg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-forsberg)) is to nest `CDF` into `Histogram`:

```
import java.util.*
import kotlin.math.max
import kotlin.math.min
import kotlin.math.roundToInt
import kotlin.random.Random


// 10 buckets for interval [0, 1000], outliers will be clamped
class Histogram {
    private val data: MutableMap<Int, Int> = mutableMapOf()
    fun add(value: Int) {
        val bucket = max(0, min(1000, value)) / 100
        data[bucket] = data.getOrDefault(bucket, 0) + 1
    }

    // cumulative distribution function
    class CDF(
        histogram: Histogram
    ) {
        private val data: SortedMap<Int, Double> = deriveCDFData(histogram)
        fun getQuantile(value: Double): Double? {
            val bucket = (10 * value).roundToInt()
            return data[bucket]
        }

        private fun deriveCDFData(histogram: Histogram): SortedMap<Int, Double> {
            val data = histogram.data
            val sum = data.values.sum()
            val pdfData = data.toSortedMap().mapValues { it.value.toDouble() / sum }
            val cdfData: MutableMap<Int, Double> = mutableMapOf()
            var acc = 0.0
            pdfData.forEach {
                acc += pdfData.getOrDefault(it.key, 0.0)
                cdfData[it.key] = acc
            }
            return cdfData.toSortedMap()
        }
    }
}


fun main() {
    val hist = Histogram()
    List(10000) {
        Random.nextInt(0, 1000)
    }.forEach {
        hist.add(it)
    }
    val cdf = (Histogram::CDF)(hist)
    println(cdf.getQuantile(0.3))
}
```